# Meteor Iron-Router Registering helper with current route runs before router is loaded

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-helper

Registering helper with current route returns error in console:

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined
```

And after Router is loaded - works fine.
How to get rid of this console error?

**Helper code:**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  // create global {{route}} helper
  Handlebars.registerHelper('route', function () {
    return Router.current().route.getName();
  });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use technique called [guarding](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards):

```
    // create global {{route}} helper
  Handlebars.registerHelper('route', function () {
    return Router.current() && 
           Router.current().route &&  
           Router.current().route.getName &&
           Router.current().route.getName();
  });
```

Comment: would it return false until the `route.getName()` is available?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add an additional parameter in your template data in the `onAfterAction` hook of your route:

```
onAfterAction: function() {
  this.data.route = this.current().route.getName();
}
```

Once you have done that, you can access your route using `yourTemplate.data.route`

The code is untested.